# Bind click event on select option

Tags: jquery

I've got a problem making a `click` event on an HTML `option` element work.

Even a simple `console.log('hello!');` won't work.

I am trying with this:

```
$('#mySelect option').bind('click', function(){
  console.log('hi!');
});
```

It worked for a while, but then stopped.

Comment: What have you changed lately? what version of jQuery are you using? how is it being loaded? Where in the page (or include scripts) are you calling this function in relation to loading the element? Is the element being generated dynamically or statically?

Comment: last changes i think doesn't matter because it won't work even if i git checkout to last working version...jQuery version is the latest and is loaded dinamically in the footer...the option element is generated from php script at onload

Comment: well for starters, if jQuery is loaded in the footer, where is this loaded?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In my case following code works

```
$('#myItem').change(function(){
            //do somthing
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can bind using `.on()` by giving `<select>` id. In general, `change` is the event called upon `<select>`.

So, there is no need to mention `option` while binding event.

```
$(document).on('change','#mySelect', function(){<br>
    console.log('hi!');
});
```

**OR**

```
$('#mySelect').bind('change',function(){<br>
    console.log('hi!');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This solve the case - for my needs (to catch the event when some of the select element on my page is clicked). Have not validated touch behavior though but Firefox, Chrome seems to be OK w/ this

```
$('.class_for_select').focus(function() {
    // do something here
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Sample example will show how to change dropdown values and color for the OPTION on click or change of select

HTML:

```
<select name="options">
      <option value="1">Red</option>
      <option value="2" selected="1">Green</option>
      <option value="3">Blue</option>
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
$("select").on("click", function () {
    debugger;
    var sVal = $(this).val();
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    $(this).find("option").css("background", "white");
    $(this).find('option:selected').css("background-color", "red");
    $("input").val($(this).val());
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n3nFB/1492/)

Answer (score 1):

Check this js fiddle --

http://jsfiddle.net/4W826/

**HTML**

```
<select id="mySelect">
               <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
               <option value="saab">Saab</option>
               <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
               <option value="audi">Audi</option>
       </select>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('#mySelect').bind('click', function(){
alert('hi!');
});
```

Change from `Click` to `Change`

Comment: This won't allow the user to change values, It shows pop up whenever I click on the select box.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use .on() instead of .bind().

```
$('#mySelect').on('change', function(){
  var $this = $(this),
      $value = $this.val();

  alert($value);

});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KHDWL/)

Answer (score 0):

because change not good enough for me  and I didn't find a way to trigger the option click what I did is

```
 $('#mySelect').click(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('optionclick') == '1') {
             $(this).attr('optionclick', '0');
        }
        else {
             $(this).attr('optionclick', '1');
        }
  });
```