# Revealing a new section dependent on selected option

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a `select` within a `form`:

```
<select id="business_type" name="business_type" class="business_type_select">
    <option value="Restaurant">Restaurant</option>
    <option value="Pub">Pub</option>
    <option value="Take Away">Take Away</option>
    <option value="Hotel">Hotel</option>
    <option value="Shop">Shop</option>
    <option value="Event">Event</option>
    <option value="Charity">Charity</option>
    <option value="Service">Service (Taxi, Tradesperson etc)</option>
    <option value="Attraction">Attraction</option>
</select>
```

I would like to do something like the jQuery slide down `toggle()` function and reveal a different `hidden` section dependent on the selection of the select id business type. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Where is your hidden section? How you gonna relate them based on selected value?

Comment: How do you identify the different hidden sections, based on the selected option?

Comment: yes, how do I indentify the hidden sections and make the correspond to the selection option. Then can i use that with Jquery to reveal them?

Comment: You also need to show the `hidden` section for getting the logic clear. Also if not created you need to add the hidden section as you want to show on the page

Comment: Look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12275153/bind-click-event-on-select-option

Comment: <div class="service">  // additional // </div>

.service {visibility: hidden;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open and hide your divs this way:

JavaScript:

```
$('#business_type').change(function(){
   $("#common div").each(function() {
       $(this).attr("style", "display: none;");
   })
   $("#" + $(this).val()).attr("style", "display: block;");
})
```

HTML:

```
<form>
<select id="business_type" name="business_type" class="business_type_select">
    <option value="Restaurant" onclick="listenerSelect()">Restaurant</option>
    <option value="Pub">Pub</option>
    <option value="Take_Away">Take Away</option>
    <option value="Hotel">Hotel</option>
    <option value="Shop">Shop</option>
    <option value="Event">Event</option>
    <option value="Charity">Charity</option>
    <option value="Service">Service (Taxi, Tradesperson etc)</option>
    <option value="Attraction">Attraction</option>
</select>
</form>
<div id="common">
<div id="Pub" style="display: none;">
    Pub
</div>
<div id="Take_Away" style="display: none;">
    Take Away
</div>
<div id="Hotel" style="display: none;">
    Hotel
</div>
<div id="Shop" style="display: none;">
    Shop
</div>
<div id="Event" style="display: none;">
    Event
</div>
<div id="Charity" style="display: none;">
    Charity
</div>
<div id="Service" style="display: none;">
    Service
</div>
<div id="Attraction" style="display: none;">
    Attraction
</div>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/uj8efeju/

Hidden div's id and correspondent option's value must be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Add a common class which will help you hide all section. then using class selector you can show the selected section.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //Bind click handler
  $('#business_type').change(function() {

    $('.common').hide(); //Hide all sections 

    $('.' + $(this).val()).show(); //Show selected section
  }).change();
});
```

```css
.common {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="business_type" name="business_type" class="business_type_select">
  <option value="charity">Charity</option>
  <option value="service">Service (Taxi, Tradesperson etc)</option>
  <option value="attraction">Attraction</option>
</select>


<div class="service common">service additional</div>
<div class="charity common">charity additional</div>
<div class="attraction common">attraction additional</div>
```