# jQuery .on() method woking on Firefox but not on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, firefox

I am trying to create a specific functionality on my web page, which uses jQuery to iterate over a JSON object, populates a combo box with its values, and also attach click event handlers to the options using jQuery's `.on()` method.

All seemed to be working fine, **until I decided to test the functionality on Google Chrome.** (I had been developing on Firefox Developer Edition till now).
**The `.on()` method from jQuery does not seem to be working on Google Chrome at all.**

**Here is the HTML code snippet for my web page**

```
<div id="showotherinfo">
    <div class="form-group" id="existingRedirection" style="">
        <label for="serviceNameList">Select a Pretty Redirection to edit it, or add a new one below</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="serviceNameList" name="serviceNameList">
            <option value="0">-Add New-</option>
            <option value="57">Infibeam Redirection</option>
            <option value="53">Mozilla Developers Redirection</option>
            <option value="56">SnapDeal Redirection</option>
        </select>
        <hr style="height: 1px; border: none; color: #333; background-color: #333;">                                                    
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Service Name<font color="red" size=3>*</font></label> 
        <input class="form-control" name="name" id="name">  
    </div>
     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="serviceUrl">Target URL<font color="red" size=3>*</font></label> 
        <input class="form-control" name="serviceUrl" id="serviceUrl">
    </div>
    <label for="prettyUrl">Pretty URL<font color="red" size=3>*</font></label>
    <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="prettyUrl" id="prettyUrl" >
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 19px;">
        <label for="redirectType">Redirect Type<font color="red" size=3>*</font></label> 
        <select class="form-control"
            name="redirectType" id="redirectType">
            <option value="0" SELECTED>-Redirection Type-</option>
            <option value="307">Temporary(307)</option>
            <option value="301">Permanent(301)</option>
            <option value="302">Found(302)</option>
        </select> 
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label style="font-weight: bold;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="nofollow" id="nofollow">
            NoFollow this link
        </label> 
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button id="saveRIP" type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
                onclick="saveData('save')">Save</button>
        <button id="updateRIP" type="button"
                class="btn btn-primary" onclick="saveData('update')"
                >Update</button>
        <button id="delete" type="button" class="btn btn-danger"
        onclick="saveData('delete')">Delete</button>
        <button id="resetRIP" type="button"
                class="btn btn-danger" onclick="resetValue()" style="margin-left: 45px;">Reset</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**And here is the jQuery code that does all the work**

```
var $select = $('#serviceNameList');
var $firstOption = $("<option/>");
$firstOption.attr("value", 0);
$firstOption.text("-Add New-");

$firstOption.on('click', function() {
    $('#name').val("");
    $('#serviceUrl').val("");
    $('#prettyUrl').val("");
    $('#redirectType').val("");

    $('#nofollow').removeAttr('checked');

    $('#saveRIP').show();
    $('#updateRIP').hide();
    $('#delete').hide();
});

$select.append($firstOption);

$(jsonResponse).each(function (index, o) {    
    var $option = $("<option/>");
    $option.attr("value", o.id);

    $option.on('click', function()  {
        $('#name').val(o.service_name);
        $('#serviceUrl').val(o.service_url);
        $('#prettyUrl').val(o.pretty_url);
        $('#redirectType').val(o.redirect_type);

        if (o.no_follow == 1)   {
            $('#nofollow').prop("checked", true);
        }
        else    {
            $('#nofollow').prop("checked", false);
        }

        $('#saveRIP').hide();

        $('#updateRIP').show();
        $('#delete').show();
    });

    $option.text(o.service_name);
    $select.append($option);
});

if ($("#serviceNameList option:selected").val() == 0)   {
    $('#saveRIP').show();

    $('#updateRIP').hide();
    $('#delete').hide();
}
```

And here is the JSFiddle link- http://jsfiddle.net/6uy1quLg/5/
(Try running it on both Google Chrome and Firefox to see the difference)

As is evident from the fiddle, the code to populate the combo box is working just fine, **but to code to attach click event handler doesn't seem to be executing at all.**

Can anybody please help me out regarding this?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$("<option/>")` is not a valid selector. use `$("option")` instead.

Comment: @northkildonan- No effect!!! :( :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the approach I would take,

use the 'change' event for handling the option change and 'data' attribute for storing the values.

http://jsfiddle.net/jmv1ck4r/3/

```
var string = '[{"service_url":"www.infibeam.com","service_name":"Infibeam Redirection","no_follow":0,"pretty_url":"infibeam","id":57,"redirect_type":"307"},{"service_url":"developer.mozilla.com","service_name":"Mozilla Developers Redirection","no_follow":0,"pretty_url":"mozilla-developers","id":53,"redirect_type":"301"},{"service_url":"www.snapdeal.com","service_name":"SnapDeal Redirection","no_follow":1,"pretty_url":"snapdeal","id":56,"redirect_type":"301"}]';

var jsonObj = JSON.parse(string);

var $select = $('#serviceNameList');
var $firstOption = $("<option/>");
$firstOption.attr("value", 0);
$firstOption.text("-Add New-");
$select.append($firstOption);

$(jsonObj).each(function (index, o) {    
    var $option = $("<option/>");
    $option.attr("value", o.id);    
    $option.text(o.service_name);
    //use data attr
    $option.data('service_name', o.service_name);
    $option.data('service_url',o.service_url);

    $select.append($option);
});

$select.on('change', function()
           {
               var selectedValue = $(this).val();

               if (selectedValue == 0)
               {
                   $('#name').val("");
                    $('#serviceUrl').val("");
                    $('#prettyUrl').val("");
                    $('#redirectType').val("");

                    $('#nofollow').removeAttr('checked');

                    $('#saveRIP').show();
                    $('#updateRIP').hide();
                    $('#delete').hide();
               }
               else
               {
                   var selectedOption = $(this).find(':selected');

                   $('#name').val($(selectedOption).data('service_name'));
                    $('#serviceUrl').val($(selectedOption).data('service_url'));
               }
           });

if ($("#serviceNameList option:selected").val() == 0)   {
    $('#saveRIP').show();   
    $('#updateRIP').hide();
    $('#delete').hide();
}
```

Comment: @Vim- Thanks!!! Its works like a charm.... I just had to add the code to check the nofollow check box if o.no_follow is 1, and that's it!!! Great!!!

Answer (score 0):

Select's option tag dont really have or can have a click event, what you have to do its to bind a "change" event to the select

you can check [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12275153/bind-click-event-on-select-option) to clear your mind a little.

Comment: If that is really the case, then why is my code working fine on Firefox? I am curious to know that...

Comment: As of my experience, browsers dont have always the same behavior and that's because each browser is made with a different thinking, maybe mozilla belive that options are elements by itself, so the should have the same events as any other tag/element, google with chrome on the other side may think the opossite, they are value options, the tag its used to describe it more semantically, but they do not represent an element on the page, so they don't get any event to be binded to, I'm just making up stories, haven't done any kind of research. :p

Comment: Try a simple console.log on the change event (the change event must be attached to the select element, not the options)

Comment: As Chichozell said, use 'change' event and, use 'data' attribute for storing the necessary values in an option. See the fiddler here and the same in posted answer -> http://jsfiddle.net/jmv1ck4r/3/. This will work in both chrome and firefox.